# Is it possible to query public Big Query Data Sets using scripts without registering for billing

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to query public Big Query Data Sets such as https://www.githubarchive.org/ using C#/python scripts   without registering for billing on Google Big Query.  I have used the C# code attached but it gives me Insufficient Permission [403] error

```
                using System;
                using System.Collections.Generic;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Text;
                using System.Threading.Tasks;
                using System.Data;
                using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

                using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
                using Google.Apis.Services;
                using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
                using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
                using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data;
                using Google.Apis.Util;

                namespace BQTry
                {
                    public class BigQueryConsole
                    {
                        static string query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM [githubarchive:year.2014]";
                        static string projectId = "some project id";

                        public static void Main(string[] args)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("BigQueryAPI STARTINg");
                            Console.WriteLine("==========================");

                            String serviceAccountEmail = "someaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

                            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"G:\CW and Research\TERM 2\SM\PROJECT\Code\BQTry\key\somekye.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                               {
                                   Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.DevstorageReadOnly }
                               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                            // Create the service.
                            var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                            {
                                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                                ApplicationName = "BigQuery API Sample",
                            });

                            //Note: all your requests will run against Service.
                            JobsResource j = service.Jobs;
                            QueryRequest qr = new QueryRequest();
                            qr.Query = query;
                            QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, projectId).Execute();

                        }
                     }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you do, you will need to enable billing, or send the credentials from a project that did.

So quick answer to your question : no. You will need to enable billing. Doesn't mean that, if all you do is query the public datasets, you'll pay.

As indicated [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) and in the linked docs on this page, the first TB of processed data each month is free.

Comment: Thanks Patrice As I  cant use my script without registering I have now manually run my queries on Google Big Query  few times and  downloaded the data.